# Need to delete three consecutive days excluding weekends and holidays in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to delete rows from a table with three consecutive days (exclude the days if weekends come in between)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [Scanid] [bigint] NULL,
    [Employeeid] [int] NULL,
    [Datescanned] [datetime] NULL
) 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([Scanid], [Employeeid], [Datescanned])
VALUES (108639, 3820, '2016-04-28 17:12:33.000'),
       (108639, 3820, '2016-04-28 18:05:46.000'),
       (108639, 3820, '2016-04-28 20:58:36.000'),
       (999999, 3820, '2016-04-29 10:08:00.000'),
       (999999, 3820, '2016-04-29 10:12:10.000'),
       (777777, 3820, '2016-05-02 10:12:00.000'),
       (111111, 3820, '2016-04-04 10:12:00.000'),
       (33333, 3820, '2016-04-11 17:23:00.000'),
       (987623, 3820, '2016-04-18 11:12:00.000'),
       (1234, 3820, '2016-05-26 10:00:00.000'),
       (5678, 3820, '2016-05-27 10:00:00.000'),
       (8920, 3820, '2016-05-31 10:00:00.000')
```

Output:

```
Scanid  Employeeid  Datescanned
----------------------------------------
108639  3820    2016-04-28 17:12:33.000
108639  3820    2016-04-28 18:05:46.000
108639  3820    2016-04-28 20:58:36.000
999999  3820    2016-04-29 10:08:00.000
999999  3820    2016-04-29 10:12:10.000
777777  3820    2016-05-02 10:12:00.000
111111  3820    2016-04-04 10:12:00.000
33333   3820    2016-04-11 17:23:00.000
987623  3820    2016-04-18 11:12:00.000
1234    3820    2016-05-26 10:00:00.000
5678    3820    2016-05-27 10:00:00.000
8920    3820    2016-05-31 10:00:00.000
```

We can take date only from datescanned field and then in the above example we should delete rows with 3 consecutive date from '2016-04-28' to '2016-05-02' (2016-04-30 and 31 are weekends so we can ignore) and also delete rows with 3 consecutive date from '2016-05-26' to '2016-05-31' (2016-05-29 and 30th are weekends so we can ignore). so only results should display row with days 2016-04-04,2016-04-11,2016-04-18 which don't have 3 consecutive days before or after them.

Comment: i removed the `mysql` tag and added sql server as the syntax looks like it/

Comment: This gets into some tricky coding. First, you will need a table containing holiday data, since this is not built in to SQL anywhere. It might be simplest to create a dates table which contains all dates for the next 20 years with a bit flag indicating if the day is a working weekday. Once that exists, it becomes a much simpler task to determine what days need to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the exact output that you want..

I could see one mistake in your question,[ie. delete  rows with 3 consecutive date from '2016-05-26' to '2016-05-31' (***2016-05-29*** and ***30th*** are weekends so we can ignore)'],those  weekends days are not correct..and the correct dates are ***2016-05-28*** and ***2016-05-29***.

```
DROP TABLE [TestDates]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestDates](
        [Scanid] [bigint] NULL,
        [Employeeid] [int] NULL,
        [Datescanned] [datetime] NULL
        )

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestDates]  ([Scanid] ,[Employeeid],[Datescanned])
    VALUES   (108639,3820,'2016-04-28 17:12:33.000'),(108639,3820,'2016-04-28 18:05:46.000'),
             (108639,3820,'2016-04-28 20:58:36.000'),(999999,3820,'2016-04-29 10:08:00.000'),
             (999999,3820,'2016-04-29 10:12:10.000'),(777777,3820,'2016-05-02 10:12:00.000'),
             (111111,3820,'2016-04-04 10:12:00.000'),(33333,3820,'2016-04-11 17:23:00.000'),
             (987623,3820,'2016-04-18 11:12:00.000'),(1234,3820,'2016-05-26 10:00:00.000'),
             (5678,3820,'2016-05-27 10:00:00.00'), (8920, 3820, '2016-05-30 10:00:00.000')
GO

DROP TABLE #t
GO
SELECT DISTINCT Employeeid,CONVERT(date,Datescanned) Datescanned INTO #T
FROM [TestDates]
GO


;WITH cte_cnt
AS
(
 SELECT Employeeid, MIN(Datescanned) AS FROM_DATE
       ,MAX(Datescanned) AS TO_DATE
       , COUNT('A') AS DayDiff
 FROM (
      SELECT Employeeid,Datescanned,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Datescanned) AS ROW_NUMBER,
            DATEDIFF(D, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Datescanned)
            ,CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, cast (Datescanned as datetime)-1) = 'Sunday' THEN DATEADD(DAY, -2, Datescanned)  ELSE Datescanned END) AS Diff
        FROM #t) AS dt
 GROUP BY Employeeid, Diff )
DELETE t
--SELECT *
FROM  cte_cnt  c
      JOIN [TestDates] t
            ON c.Employeeid=t.Employeeid
WHERE CAST(t.Datescanned as DATE) BETWEEN c.FROM_DATE AND  c.TO_DATE and c.DayDiff=3
GO

SELECT *
FROM [TestDates]
GO
```

Comment: I tested it and its working perfectly. I am really impressed by the way you coded this. Thanks. Now I have additional requirement to avoid holidays also. So I guess I need to use calender period table to get only working days and inner join it will my table and delete three consecutive rows

Comment: Great..let me know once you completed with the holiday calendar..  By the way give an upvote also.. :)

Comment: I cretaed Test_calendar table removing all holidays and weekends and assigned row number to active days. Then this is the code I used. It working but may not be the fast if we have millions of rows. For me data is small so it will get the work done. Please let me know if you can simplify deletion process to make it fast.

Comment: I am not able to post the code here. I posted it as an answer to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?:

```
delete from Test
where not exists (
    select 1
    from Test t2
    where cast(t2.Datescanned as date)
        between
            dateadd(day,
                case datepart(dayofweek, cast(Test.Datescanned as date))
                    when 1 then -4 when 2 then -4
                    else -2
                end,
                cast(Test.Datescanned as date)
            )
        and
            dateadd(day,
                case datepart(dayofweek, cast(Test.Datescanned as date))
                    when 4 then 4 when 5 then 4
                    else 2
                end,
                cast(Test.Datescanned as date)
            )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution which doesn't account for holidays would be

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
  CAST(t1.datescanned AS date) first_date,
  CAST(t2.datescanned AS date) second_date,
  CAST(t3.datescanned AS date) third_date
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 --add a join condition for employeeid as well
  ON DATEDIFF(dd, CAST(t1.datescanned AS date), CAST(t2.datescanned AS date)) = 1
  OR (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CAST(t2.datescanned AS date)) = 2
  AND DATEDIFF(dd, CAST(t1.datescanned AS date), CAST(t2.datescanned AS date)) = 3)
JOIN test t3 --add a join condition for employeeid as well
  ON DATEDIFF(dd, CAST(t2.datescanned AS date), CAST(t3.datescanned AS date)) = 1
  OR (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CAST(t3.datescanned AS date)) = 2
  AND DATEDIFF(dd, CAST(t2.datescanned AS date), CAST(t3.datescanned AS date)) = 3)
 ) x
JOIN test t
  ON CAST(t.datescanned AS date) = x.first_date
  OR CAST(t.datescanned AS date) = x.second_date
  OR CAST(t.datescanned AS date) = x.third_date
```

Self join the table twice, each time on

- a date difference of 1 or
- 3 when a weekend occurs and check if the weekday is Monday (weekday=2)

[**`Sample demo`**](http://rextester.com/SIB34409)

The result gives the rows which need to be deleted. But the caveat here is that, this would give you more than 3 consecutive days if there are no gaps. In that case you need to explain if you want to stop deleting at the 3rd day.

Answer (score 0):

The previous scripts are good. I would make an improvement and for weekend and Holiday check, add a function and call it in the select statement. 
Here is a simple function that you can use (I am assuming that you have a table called Holiday, which holds all holiday dates per State )

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[IsHolidayOrWeekend] 
(
    @date DateTime,
    @stateId int
)
RETURNS Bit
AS
BEGIN
    declare @dayOfWeek VARCHAR(9);
    set @dayOfWeek = DATEName(DW, @date);

    IF(@dayOfWeek = 'Saturday' OR @dayOfWeek = 'Sunday') 
        RETURN 1;
    ELSE
    begin
        set @date = cast(@date as date) -- Remove the time portion 
        RETURN IsNull((SELECT 1 from Holiday where StateId = @provinceId and HolidayDate = @date ), 0)
    end;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an added requirement to igonre holidays also along with weekend. I cretaed Test_calendar table removing all holidays and weekends and assigned row number to active days. Then this is the code I used. It working but may not be the fast if we have millions of rows. For me data is small so it will get the work done. Please let me know if you can simplify deletion process to make it fast.

```
SELECT  distinct scanid as [badgeid] , Employeeid,CONVERT(date, Datescanned) as Datescanned,RN
   into #test1
    FROM [dbo].[Test] a
     inner join Test_Calendar b
  on CONVERT(date, a.Datescanned)=b.Cal_date
    order by Datescanned asc


  declare @min int
  declare @max int
  declare @i int
  select @min=MIN(rn) from #test1
  select @max=Max(rn) from #test1
  while(@min<@max)
  begin
  select @i=COUNT(*) from #test1 where rn in(@min ,@min+1,@min+2)
  if(@i=3)
  select *  from #test1 where rn in(@min ,@min+1,@min+2)
  set @min=@min+1 
  end
```